# calling componentDidMount when routed from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to re-fetch in componentDidMount lifecycle of a parent component when an item in a child component is deleted? But it does not seem that once it is called at the initial rendering of parent route, routing it back using this.context.router.push does not trigger componentDidMount anymore in the parent route. Anyone has suggestion to get around this? much appreciated.

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchData(
      // update state
    )
  }
  render () {
    // render with updated data
  }
}

export class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchData(
      // update state
    )
  }
  deleteItem () {
    this.props.deleteItem(id, (res) => {
      this.context.router.push('/parentroute')
    })
  }
  render () {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`componentDidMount` is only called once and after the component has mounted.

If you want to call a parent component method multiple times you can you use `componentWillReceiveProps` in the parent component.

Alternatively you could use the child `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` hooks but probably best to deal with it in the parent.